# Entity Framework Migrations APIs for C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Are there any APIs to call Entity Framework Migrations from C#?

Instead of using `dotnet ef add migrations Initial`, I am providing an interface to the user to install the system.

User shall select the database properties and the system should be able to create migrations from all different assemblies and create the database for the user.

I have not found any documentation for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime migrations can be run at runtime. eg:

```
myDbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Once you have 50 reputation, you can comment.  And a bare docs link is typically provided in a comment.  And when you are linking to the official docs, a very short quote is enough.  Like my edit above.